# The images defined in CSS files did not work with spring mvc

Tags: css, image, spring, model-view-controller, resources

I used eclipse to create a SPRING MVC 3.0 app. I have a simple controller and JSP view. And I used a CSS file to specifies the page style. When I opened this view, I found the style worked and the pictures didn't work. My directory structure looks like bellow:

```
 webapp
 webapp-resource
 webapp-resource-css
 webapp-resource-css-login.css
 webapp-resource-image
 webapp-resource-image-bg.jpg
```

The JSP files looks like bellow:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/css/login.css"/>" />
</head>
```

The CSS files looks like bellow:

```
body {
background: #eeeeee url(../images/bg.jpg) top left repeat;
}
```

The resource configured likes bellow:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/resources/images/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/resources/css/" />
```

When I used the HTTP tools to watch the requset, I found that the picture was marked with "text\html".

```
/pangpang/css/login.css;jsessionid=WptcUNivFhWbnYsthGjMLeB8  GET 200 text/css  <link rel="stylesheet">
/pangpang/images/form-bg.png                                 GET 404 text/html background-image
```

Answer (score 0):

The `text/html` content type is likely because the 404 response has also some text/html content that the image is not found (the "normal" resource not found page).

I think the problem is: you query from `form-bg.png` but your file has the name `bg.jpg` (without `form` prefix)

Comment: Hi Ralph,<br/>Thanks for your help. I confirmed that the images referenced in CSS files are present. I referenced a lot of pictures in CSS files. I am jsut using the 'form-bg.png' as an example.

Comment: I had resolved the problem. The root cause is that I used the wrong folder name 'image' instead of 'images'.